# Unity ioc - how to pass parameters to the constructor of the dependent object

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

For example

```
class SocketWrapper : ISocketWrapper
{ 
  public SocketWrapper(String ip, int port)
  {
  }
  // interface method
  public void DoSomethig()
  {
  }
}

class DataConnector  
{
  public DataConnector(ISocketWrapper conn)
  {
  }
}
```

in my app i'm write

```
unity.RegisterType(typeof(ISocketWrapper), typeof(SocketWrapper))
unity.Resolve(typeof(DataConnector))
```

and i have expetion,
how to pass parameters  to the constructor of the dependent object (SocketWrapper) on resloving object "DataConnector"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to pass parameters like this using Unity:

```
unity.Resolve<DataConnector>(new ParameterOverride("SomePropertyName", someValue), new   ParameterOverride("SomeOtherProperty", someOtherValue)
```